# GUI programming in Clojure/Clojurescript - 'zoomable directed acyclic graphs'

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, graph, clojure

I'm designing a GUI and want to find a library **on the JVM or for javascript** that I can use with Clojure or Clojurescript.

**The problem:**

I need to display **'zoomable' directed acyclic graphs** (DAGs). A picture is worth 1000 words, so here is what the interface ought to look like, and how the screen changes under 'zooming':

[image]

Specifically, every node can have its own internal graph, with the restriction that each inner graph has the same number of inputs and outputs as the node itself.

My experience with graphics is limited in Javascript and nonexistent in Java, but...

**My ideas:**

1. Naively draw the whole graph with all 'inner graphs' already inside the nodes, and fade the inner graphs out for text when the zoom level is sufficiently far away. Use click events to change the zoom to and from this level. I don't think this will behave well when there are several nested inner graphs.
2. Draw the unzoomed graph and zoom into a node when clicked so that its background fills the screen, then overlay the inner graph. For nested inner graphs do the same trick, maintaining a 'background node' and 'inner graph'.

Is option 2 sensible? If so is there a library (ie graphviz) I can modify to achieve this behaviour? If there isn't a library, what framework (ie JavaFX) should I use?

Comment: In CLJS, you might be able to use [JointJS](http://www.jointjs.com/) to achieve your goal.

Comment: Consider [d3.js](https://d3js.org) with cljs.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about struggling with Java interop syntax, I can highly recommend [FXDiagram](http://jankoehnlein.github.io/FXDiagram/):

> Selected features:
>
> - Modern graphics [based on JavaFX]
> - Suggestive metaphors
> - Optimized for usability
> - Multi-touch gestures
> - Smooth transitions/animations
> - Animated auto-layout (based on [KIELER](http://www.rtsys.informatik.uni-kiel.de/en/research/kieler/) and [Graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org/))
> - Animated undo/redo
> - JSON persistence
> - SVG export
> - Xtext/Eclipse integration
> - Graphical context menu
> - …and much more

It's open source (and active), written in [Xtend](http://www.eclipse.org/xtend/) and easily integrates models expressed in [Xtext](http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/)-based DSLs.